# Wire gauge needed for outbuilding with welder

Tags: wiring, subpanel

I have a standalone building that I'm going to start welding and doing other metal work out of. When looking over the current wiring I came across a wild shock that all I could do was laugh.

The lights and one outlet is powered by a cut up cheap extension cord and the one 220 outlet is straight wired and shallow (2 inches) buried to the oven breaker.

With that said I went and got a  100amp panel, 100amp breaker for the main panel.

My question is: **What wire do I need to run to the sub panel?**

It is 74 feet from the main panel and at most I would be running lights, radio and fan (all 110) along with my millermatic 251 (220) at one time. The welder and a air compressor are the only things that would be 220. I don't have a clue as to what amperage that would be but I would rather have done over kill than to be pushing my luck.  Thanks in advance for any and all help.  P.S I don't know shit about electrical work.

Comment: Where do you live?  What you're allowed to do depends on location.  The magic word for how much current a wire can carry is ampacity.  If you want a 100A panel, you need 100A wire which based on your electrical code you may need to derate, meaning treat it like it can carry less current and embiggen it based on temperature, length, or how many other wires are in proximity.    This exact question came up today or yesterday though, and I believe without derating factors you need 1 AWG Aluminum or 3 AWG Copper.

Comment: You also need to know how deep you have to bury it, with or without mechanical protection and make sure you have room for a 100A breaker in the panel you're running out of, which you probably did if you've already purchased the breaker.  You can get cable for direct burial, but last I checked it was significantly cheaper to bury conduit and pull wire.  Don't be afraid to oversize your conduit.  It makes the pulling easier.  Anyway, where do you live?  My advice may not be useful.  Make sure you talk to the permit office at least before you bury pipe as you don't want to have to dig it up.

Comment: I live in Georgia and the depth is 24 inches

Comment: What're the amp and HP ratings on your air compressor?  How many square feet is the building in question, for that matter? Also, what make/model of panel did you buy?

Comment: P.S. according to [this specsheet](https://www.red-d-arc.com/pdf/Millermatic%20251%20Spec%20Sheet.pdf), your Millermatic 251 has a rated primary current of 42A @ 230VAC and a maximum duty cycle of 60%

Comment: With air compressors go off the MFG data tag not the phony horse power rating. Both air compressors and vacuum cleaners / shop vacuums lie on there horsepower rating we can help you calculate that with the info on the data tag on the motor.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but the building is 120 square feet the compressor is a sears craftsman 5hp 20 gallon. They only thing I can find on the motor at this point is caution may burn tag. It is over 20 years old